# SELECT 1 from DUAL: MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

In looking over my Query log, I see an odd pattern that I don't have an explanation for.

After practically every query, I have "select 1 from DUAL".

I have no idea where this is coming from, and I'm certainly not making the query explicitly.

The log basically looks like this:

```
    10 Query       SELECT some normal query
    10 Query       select 1 from DUAL
    10 Query       SELECT some normal query
    10 Query       select 1 from DUAL
    10 Query       SELECT some normal query
    10 Query       select 1 from DUAL
    10 Query       SELECT some normal query
    10 Query       select 1 from DUAL
    10 Query       SELECT some normal query
    10 Query       select 1 from DUAL
    ...etc...
```

Has anybody encountered this problem before?

MySQL Version: 5.0.51

Driver: Java 6 app using JDBC. mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar

Connection Pool: commons-dbcp 1.2.2

The validationQuery was set to "select 1 from DUAL" (obviously) and apparently the connection pool defaults testOnBorrow and testOnReturn to true when a validation query is non-null.

One further question that this brings up for me is whether or not I actually **need** to have a validation query, or if I can maybe get a performance boost by disabling it or at least reducing the frequency with which it is used.  Unfortunately, the developer who wrote our "database manager" is no longer with us, so I can't ask him to justify it for me. Any input would be appreciated. I'm gonna dig through the API and google for a while and report back if I find anything worthwhile.

EDIT: added some more info

EDIT2: Added info that was asked for in the correct answer for anybody who finds this later

Comment: what connection pool are you using?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It could be coming from the connection pool your application is using. We use a simple query to test the connection.

Just had a quick look in the source to mysql-connector-j and it isn't coming from in there.

The most likely cause is the connection pool.

Common connection pools:

**commons-dbcp** has a configuration property `validationQuery`, this combined with `testOnBorrow` and `testOnReturn` could cause the statements you see.

**c3p0** has `preferredTestQuery`, `testConnectionOnCheckin`, `testConnectionOnCheckout` and `idleConnectionTestPeriod`

For what's it's worth I tend to configure connection testing and checkout/borrow even if it means a little extra network chatter.

Comment: Thanks very much for your edit, as it put me straight down the right path, as indicated in my edited OP.

What are the consequences of removing the validation query, or setting testOnBorrow/testOnReturn/etc to false?  Is there any way to reduce the frequency, instead of removing it completely?

Comment: What usually happens if you don't have some sort validation is that the db connection times out over night and the first X logins in the morning fail because they have a stale connection. commons-dbcp has testWhileIdle this will run the validation query in another thread and the timings are configurable. As I've said above I'd just leave it on testOnBorrow until you are really pushing the performance limits of your network/hardware

Answer (score 5):

I have performed 100 inserts/deltes and tested on both DBCP and C3PO.

DBCP :: testOnBorrow=true impacts the response time by more than 4 folds.

C3P0 :: testConnectionOnCheckout=true impacts the response time by more than 3 folds.

Here are the results :
DBCP – BasicDataSource

Average time for 100 transactions ( insert operation ) 
testOnBorrow=false ::  219.01 ms
testOnBorrow=true  :: 1071.56 ms

Average time for 100 transactions ( delete opration ) 
testOnBorrow=false ::  223.4 ms
testOnBorrow=true  :: 1067.51 ms

C3PO – ComboPooledDataSource
Average time for 100 transactions ( insert operation ) 
testConnectionOnCheckout=false ::   220.08 ms
testConnectionOnCheckout=true  ::   661.44 ms

Average time for 100 transactions ( delete opration ) 
testConnectionOnCheckout=false ::   216.52 ms
testConnectionOnCheckout=true  ::   648.29 ms

Conculsion : Setting testOnBorrow=true in DBCP or testConnectionOnCheckout=true in C3PO impacts the performance by 3-4 folds. Is there any other setting that will enhance the performance.

-Durga Prasad

Answer (score 2):

The "dual" table/object name is an Oracle construct, which MySQL supports for compatibility - or to provide a target for queries that dont have a target but people want one to feel all warm and fuzzy. E.g.

```
select curdate()
```

can be

```
select curdate() from dual
```

Someone could be sniffing you to see if you're running Oracle.

Comment: I don't see how that could determine if they're using oracle.  Especially since you state in your answer that MySQL supports it as well.  I don't believe it's limited to those two either.  It's just a generic dummy table name.  I've also seen people add a DUAL table into databases on PostgreSQL for compatibility.